# add level to json object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have the following output of json using c# json serialization. It gets populated from a C# data table. I need to add a level to the object.

**UPDATE**
How would I make this an array of strings, instead of an array of objects?

```
[{
    "Urgency": "C",
    "Picker": null,
    "CARD": null,
},
{
    "Urgency": "C",
    "Picker": null,
    "CARD": null,
}]
```

the end result should be

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "Urgency": "C",
        "Picker": null,
        "CARD": null,
    },
    {
        "Urgency": "C",
        "Picker": null,
        "CARD": null,
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I add that top level to my existing json output?

Here's my loop.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
    rows.Add(row);
}
context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows).ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an anonymous class:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
  row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
   rows.Add(row);
}
context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new { data= rows }).ToString());
```

If you are using an older version of .NET then create an actual class like this:

```
public class RowsDTO {

   public Dictionary<string,object> Data { get; private set; }

   public RowsDTO(){
      data = new Dictionary<string,object>();
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I make this an array of strings, instead of an array of objects?

Comment: you mean you want the keys of the dictionary?

Comment: I can't use the above formula because it's returning an array of objects. I need to create an array of strings. So now, I am using a string array instead of a dictionary. And I'm passing that array to the JSON.